# How to force a location update on Android

Tags: android, android-studio, locationmanager

Is there an alternative to this call that will force the acquisition of new coordinates from the hardware?

```
locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

The specific problem I'm having is they are using Fake GPS to mock a location.  They turn it off before launching my app, but when my app launches and makes the above call it's still getting the last-given mock location.

Note: We've removed it from the Developer Options as the mock gps provider and done a force quit on it.  We even uninstalled it.  So I'm certain that Android itself is still caching the prior mock value and just feeding that to my app because the phone hasn't moved.

In addition, because there's no mock provider in Developer Options, Android LocationManager is reporting the cached fake location as NOT mocked.  Clearly a huge bug.

What I'd like to do is make a call that FORCES the phone to turn on GPS and acquire new coordinates.  Unfortunately I don't see any way to do this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is you have to make location request for the said provider. Provider needs a fresh location.

Long asnwer is;

> The specific problem I'm having is they are using Fake GPS to mock a location. They turn it off before launching my app, but when my app launches and makes the above call it's still getting the last-given mock location.

Under normal circumstances `getLastKnownLocation` method returns the cached location for given provider. So getting the mock location is expected in your case, because your device did not receive fresh location yet

> Note: We've removed it from the Developer Options as the mock gps provider and done a force quit on it. We even uninstalled it. So I'm certain that Android itself is still caching the prior mock value and just feeding that to my app because the phone hasn't moved.

That's right, because the mocker app's previously set location is cached for given provider. It affects the whole system. This is why it's not cleared after uninstalling the mocker app. You have to make location request for the provider or restart your device.

> In addition, because there's no mock provider in Developer Options,
>   Android LocationManager is reporting the cached fake location as NOT
>   mocked. Clearly a huge bug.

How did you test it ? All devices behave like this when you test ? Maybe the mocker app is installed as system app, so it reports location to LocationManager and dissimulates you ?

---

To force GPS to get location you can easily use below code. onLocationChanged method will be triggered by GPS hardware.

But be sure that a mock location app is not working at this time. Otherwise, onLocationChanged method will be triggered by mocker app !

```
private void requestLocation(){
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mListener);
}

private LocationListener mListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Previously mock location is cleared.
        // getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); will not return mock location. 
    }

    ...
};
```

Comment: "Short answer is you have to make location request for the said provider. Provider needs a fresh location."   I do that using 'locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);' but it keeps returning the same cached value.

Comment: "How did you test it ? All devices behave like this when you test?"  Yes, all devices.  Uninstall the Fake GPS app and turn off developer options entirely.  Then printf() the value of 'lastKnownLocation.isFromMockProvider()', which tells me the location is mocked.  NOTE: This is even after restarting our app, which flushes and renews our app's subscription to location services.

Comment: Also, NONE of my 'locationListener' methods ever get called during or as a result of the change in GPS provider.  I find that more than odd because one provider is being disabled (Fake GPS) and another is being enabled (Real GPS) during the changeover.

Comment: @Bungles for first comment,   getLastKnownLocation does not make location request.  If you (or other app like Google Maps) don't make location request it will return cached (in your case mock) location.

Comment: "If you (or other app like Google Maps) don't make location request it will return cached (in your case mock) location."  Ok. My original question is how to do that.  As far as I can see there is no API to force a location update.

Comment: If you still didn't get fresh location, and call isFromMockProvider() then it will return true.

Comment: I think this is already known but just to state it... "isFromMockProvider()" doesn't always return 'true' after Fake GPS is uninstalled.  It does work correctly some (most?) of the time, but not all.

Comment: Ok, think I found it. The 'LocationManager.requestSingleUpdate()' method APPEARS to force GPS on so the value is changed.  Is that the method you were thinking of, as opposed to the Google Play Services route?

Comment: Thanks for the update. In my case I was already subscribed via LocationListener, and as mentioned none of my LocationListener delegates get called when the transition occurs.  There is no event that triggers telling me to unsubscribe and re-subscribe, so in my case I trigger off Activity Resume and request a single update. This results in my existing LocationListener being called with the new value.

Comment: So what's happening after getting new location ? Still having problem ?

Comment: There seems to be some inconsistency across devices, but "eventually" we get new coordinates.  I'm hoping all is well, but will know after QA gets their turn at it. :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127117/discussion-between-blackkara-and-bungles).

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue from Marshmallow that reported.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=227873

Comment: Bummer. Hopefully it's something they prioritize. It's a huge problem for banking apps and similar things that require geofencing.

Comment: @Nguyen Phuc Thao can you give me your contact then we can try to find the solution. I have same problem but still can not find the way to fix :((

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest solution is in abstracting out from Android's gps tools. 
Just extract all your gps- related features into separate interface and implement it for testing without using ANY Android- related services. By doing so, you will not even need to mock your locations (assuming, your final Android implementation will work correctly). You can mock this test implementation in any way, for example, open Json file with locatioins from assets and feed it to your interface periodically. See this article : http://martinfowler.com/articles/dipInTheWild.html

Comment: I don't need to use a mock location service.  I need to notify the user when a mock location service is detected.